# What does the sentence mean in the given context?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I am confused about the meaning of the following sentence:

> He started with a scanned sketch that he traced over, alternating
>   between the two different  tools to re-create the line work.

Does the phrases "traced over" and "re-create the line work" signify a single action of tracing? Or is the action signifies by "traced over" is finished in the first clause and another action of "re-creating the line" starts in the second clause?

The text is regarding a photo editing app.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence describes the general task of re-creating the line work. He used two different tools to accomplish that task. He did not use the two tools simultaneously; he alternated between using one and then the other. What was his starting point? He traced over a scanned sketch.